# where to look if ubuntu server stop working?

Tags: server

Well I guess it is some kind of log I can see and I have look inside the

```
/var/log
```

but still can't find what have happend to my ubuntu server.

Three days in a row it just stop working and just freeze and I have to power off and then power on again. When it frezze it just stop working and I can't use SSH or the keyboard so I just have to power off. It is maybe some script I have done something wrong but when I don't know what to look after then is not easy for me to fix it :)

Answer (score 1):

`journalctl -b -1 -e` will show the end of the previous boot's logs, leading up to the last crash. `journalctl --list-boots` will show what it's possible to look at. `man journalctl` is a requirement.

Comment: Thanks for the replay
I ave no look and I can't see any error. 
When I run the first one I see no error and in the end I got this https://pastebin.com/SX2ZuqNy
The second gave me not so much
https://pastebin.com/DAWze4gh

Comment: The `journalctl --list-boots` shows that you can inspect the last 7 reboots with `for i in $( seq -7 1 -1) ; do journalctl -b $i -e; done`. Is there a common factor? If so, investigate it. If not, suspect power or overheating.

Comment: Hmm it look like "Started Clean php session files" make it stop working. Not sure how to fix that
With this server I running with 7.2.19 version of PHP. my old webserver I did use a older version of PHP